# Issues with ImageIcon and images on buttons - JFrame

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, embedded-resource

this has been driving me crazy all day so I figured I'd post it here and see if someone else can work it out. First off I tried to add a background image, the default ImageIcon was not working so I went with overriding the paint method instead. #

```
public class ImageJPanel extends JPanel { 
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1846386687175836809L;
Image image = null; 

public ImageJPanel(){ 
    addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() { 
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) { 
        ImageJPanel.this.repaint(); 
    } 
}); 
}
//Set the image.
public ImageJPanel(Image i) { 
  image=i; 
  setOpaque(false); 
} 
//Overide the paint component.
public void paint(Graphics g) { 
  if (image!=null) g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null); 
  super.paint(g); 
}
```

}

Once I used that it worked fine, however now I want to add images to my buttons but it is not working. Here is how my buttons work:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
Images images = new Images();
JPanel j = new ImageJPanel(images.menuBackground); 
j.setLayout(null);
JButton Button_1= new JButton("Button_1",new ImageIcon("images/gui/Button.png"));

Insets insets = j.getInsets();
Dimension size = Button_1.getPreferredSize();
Button_1.setBounds(300 + insets.left, 150+ insets.top, size.width, size.height);

Singleplayer.setSize(200, 50);

j.add(Button_1);

frame.add(j);
frame.setSize(800,600);
frame.setResizable(false);
Button_1.addMouseListener(singleplayerPressed);

frame.setVisible(true);
```

All my images are .png, could that affect it?

Comment: Where are the images located? PNG works just fine. Side note, you should override `paintComponent()` not `paint()`. Also make sure to call `super` implementation *before* doing all your painting.

Comment: 1) For `JPanel` override `paintComponent(Graphics)` rather than `paint(Graphics)` 2) Use `Class.getResource(String)` to locate application resources such as images (the code provides a `String` that will be interpreted as a `File` path. 3) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 4) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use it consistently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with this:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) { 
    if (image!=null) g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null); 
    super.paint(g); 
}
```

This is the wrong approach.  Firstly, you really don't want to override the paint method UNLESS you absolutely know that this is the correct approach to your problem (and without knowing more, I'd suggest it isn't).

Secondly, you paint your image on the component, then promptly paint over the top of it...(`super.paint(g);` can have the ability to paint over your work, I know the panel is opaque, but this is still a very bad approach).

Use `paintComponent` instead

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) { 
    super.paint(g); 
    if (image!=null) g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null); 
}
```

PNG images are fine, they are supported by Swing out of the box.

Make sure that your program can see the image.  Is it been loaded from the file source or is it a resource within you JAR?

Try this:

```
System.out.println(new File("images/gui/Button.png").exits());
```

If your program can see the file, it will return `true` other wise the program can not see the file and that is your problem.

Comment: `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);` Would better be `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this); // every JComponent is an ImageObserver!`

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much! That fixed the problem! The image was in the wrong place.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Copy'n'Paste +1, always keeping me on my toes ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(this.getClass()
                .getResource("images/gui/Button.png"));
```

Side note, you should override `paintComponent()` not `paint()`. Also make sure to call `super` implementation *before* doing all your painting. For more details see [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) tutorial.